# Random Matrix of Random Size With Random Sized Elements totaling a max size

Tags: python

I've been working on trying to make a random matrix generator that populates that with random sized elements.

```
import random
from collections import deque
rand_max = random.randint(1,10)
matrix = []
print("Max:",rand_max)
for num_y in range(random.randint(1,rand_max)):
    line_length = 0
    x = []
    print("Row:",num_y)
    for num_x in range(random.randint(1,(rand_max - line_length))):
        if line_length != rand_max:
            partial = []
            for num_z in range(random.randint(1, (rand_max - line_length))):
                partial.append(0)
                line_length += 1
            x.append(partial)
            continue
    print("Line is:",x)
    print("Length is:", line_length)
    matrix.append(x)
#print(matrix)
start_x = random.randint(0, len(matrix))
start_y = random.randint(0, start_x)
print("Your start location is: ","(",start_x,",",start_y,")")
next_moves = deque()
```

So it does what I want it to do most of the time, but sometimes it provides a line length that != max_length and I've been at it for a while and I'm a bit lost as to why.

Here's an example of the wrong output:

> Max: 6
>
> Row: 0
>
> Line is: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0]]
>
> Length is: 6
>
> Row: 1
>
> Line is: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0]]
>
> Length is: 6
>
> Row: 2
>
> Line is: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>
> Length is: 6
>
> Row: 3
>
> Line is: [[0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>
> Length is: 6
>
> Row: 4
>
> Line is: [[0], [0, 0, 0], [0]]
>
> Length is: 5
>
> Row: 5
>
> Line is: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0]]
>
> Length is: 6
>
> Your start location is:  ( 1 , 1 )

Occasionally my rows will leave spaces blank and I'm not sure why.

Comment: The length of a line is randomly generated. It's the sum of several random numbers (in fact, a random number of random numbers). It's often the maximum because you stop generating more when you get there, but there's nothing that prevents you from getting fewer, other than low odds.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and feel like the solution isn't far off, I'm just having a hard time seeing where to implement what you're saying. I appreciate the helpful direction

Comment: It's not obvious what you want. If you want all the lines to have the maximum length, I'd suggest adding a last item that has `rand_max - line_length` elements in it. But note that by forcing things like this, you're probably distorting the random distribution a bit. That may or may not matter to you (your code is already producing a pretty distorted distribution)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to correct it by performing a check at the end of the loop.No the level or randomization isn't a concern to me at this point. I'm just trying to crawl through a grid and record the moves I've made. I've only begun my programming adventure and this is something I wanted to do. I'm hoping to get more complex with more experience.